# Triangles in a pentagon

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

Draw a regular pentagon and its five diagonals. How many triangles are formed?

I know I can do this problem by just counting all the triangles but how do I do this faster?

Comment: You can search for the answer. on a serious note, do you know combinatrics?

Comment: yes, but I don't know how to use it for this question. I know I have to choose 3 segments to form a triangle but I don't know where to choose them from

Comment: @3bds I'd start by 'looking' at what sets of three segments **won't** yield a triangle (e.g., $\{\langle 0,1\rangle, \langle 1,2\rangle, \langle 0,3\rangle\}$, see if I can characterize the families that those fall into, and then subtract out the count of those families from the total number of sets of three segments.

Answer (score 2):

**I.** For a regular pentagon there is probably nothing faster than simply counting the triangles. But counting becomes increasingly difficult as the number of sides of a regular polygon increases.  The problem is complicated by the fact that, for regular polygons of even $n>4$ sides, one or more concurrencies of three or more diagonals occur.

But the regular pentagon and all regular polygons with an *odd* number of sides are more law-abiding, since their diagonals do not produce three-line concurrencies.  If we begin with regular pentagon $ABCDE$, and draw the diagonals in alphabetical order, we have $AC$, $AD$, $BD$, $BE$, $CE$. The number of triangles formed by $AC$, $AD$ is $1+2=3$.  $BD$, $BE$ form $6+11=17$ triangles. $CE$ forms $15$ triangles, making$$3+17+15=35$$ in all.
[image: triangles in pentagon]
**II.** In a polygon, drawing in alphabetical order all diagonals from $A$, then all those from $B$, and so on, we find that diagonals from a point to its alphabetically nearest neighbor, i.e. $AC$, $BD$, $CE$, $DF$, $EG$, ... generate $1$, $6$, $15$, $28$, $45$,... triangles, respectively.  For the $rth$ such diagonal, the number of triangles generated is thus $2r^2-r$.  But since $EG$, the fifth such diagonal here, first appears in the regular heptagon, substituting $n-2$ for $r$ we get $$2n^2-9n+10$$ with $n\ge3$.  The sum $\Sigma_1$ of these triangles is thus $$2\left(\frac{n^3}{3}+\frac{n^2}{2}+\frac{n}{6}\right)-9\left(\frac{n^2+n}{2}\right)+10n=\frac{4n^3-21n^2+35n-18}{6}$$(It is necessary to deduct $\frac{18}{6}=3$, since $n\ge3$ and $2n^2-9n+10=3$ for $n=1$, and $0$ for $n=2$.  A similar adjustment is made in determining each of the sums below.)

Diagonals drawn to vertices which are two vertices away from $A$, $B$, $C$, ... , i.e. $AD$, $BE$, $CF$, $DG$, $EH$, ... produce $1$, $11$, $29$, $55$, $89$, ... triangles, respectively.  The law of this sequence is $4n^2-18n+19$, and the sum   $\Sigma_2$, over denominator $6$ and again with $n\ge3$, is$$\frac{8n^3-42n^2+64n-24}{6}$$Since in the pentagon no diagonal joins vertices more than two vertices apart, the preceding two sums suffice for calculating how many triangles the diagonals produce.  For $CE$, the last diagonal joined in the pentagon, and the greatest term in the first sequence, $n=r+2=5$, and $$\frac{4n^3-21n^2+35n-18}{6}=22$$  For $BE$, the greatest term in the second sequence, $n=4$ and $$\frac{8n^3-42n^2+64n-24}{6}=12$$ $AD$ is the last diagonal drawn from $A$, but note that every diagonal drawn from $A$ generates one triangle in a polygon, except the last, which generates two. **Hence again, the number of triangles formed by diagonals in the regular pentagon is$$22+12+1=35$$**

**III.** Similarly, systematic counting of triangles in odd regular polygons formed by diagonals joining vertices separated by $3$, $4$, $5$, $6$ vertices, i.e.$$AE, BF, CG,...; AF, BG, CH,...; AG, BH, CI...; AH, BI, CJ...$$yields sequences$$1, 18, 48, 91, 147,...$$$$1, 27, 72, 136, 219,...$$$$1, 38, 101, 190, 305,...$$$$1, 51, 135, 253, 405,...$$whose laws, with common denominator $2$, are$$\frac{13n^2-57n+56}{2}$$$$\frac{19n^2-81n+74}{2}$$$$\frac{26n^2-108n+92}{2}$$$$\frac{34n^2-138n+110}{2}$$and whose sums $\Sigma_{3-6}$, with common denominator $6$,  are$$\frac{13n^3-66n^2+89n-18}{6}$$$$\frac{19n^3-93n^2+110n}{6}$$$$\frac{26n^3-123n^2+127n+30}{6}$$$$\frac{34n^3-156n^2+140n+72}{6}$$As we calculated the number of triangles in the regular pentagon using the first two of the preceding six sums, so we can calculate the triangles in the heptagon using the first four, and generally the number of triangles in an odd $n$-agon using $n-3$ such sums. Thus letting $n=7$, $6$, $5$, $4$, respectively, in the first four sums given above, we calculate the number of triangles in the regular heptagon as$$95+96+67+28+1=287$$Again, letting $n=9$, $8$, $7$, $6$, $5$, $4$ in the six sums above, we find that the regular nonagon contains$$252+316+305+236+140+52+1=1302$$triangles.

**IV.** Inspecting the numerators of the expressions above, for the number of triangles generated by diagonals joining points separated by $1$, $2$, $3$, ... vertices, we can discern a general rule.  Over common denominator $2$ we have$$4n^2-18n+20$$$$8n^2-36n+38$$$$13n^2-57n+56$$$$19n^2-81n+74$$$$26n^2-108n+92$$$$34n^2-138n+110$$Thus it is easy to extrapolate to corresponding sequences for polygons of ever larger odd $n$.

The summations of these successive sequences, over common denominator $6$, are likewise predictable, if slightly more complex:$$4n^3-21n^2+35n-18$$$$8n^3-42n^2+64n-24$$$$13n^3-66n^2+89n-18$$$$19n^3-93n^2+110n$$$$26n^3-123n^2+127n+30$$$$34n^3-156n^2+140n+72$$

If these extrapolations are warranted, then diagonals in the $11$, $13$, and $15$-agon generate $4257$, $11297$, and $25935$, triangles, respectively.  Lastly, the diagonals of the celebrated $17$-agon of Carl Friedrich Gauss generate $53516$ triangles!
[image: 17-agon]
Can we extract a single general rule for the number of triangles, as a function of odd $n$?

**V.** Well, the sequence obtained so far, for the number of triangles generated by the diagonals of regular polygons of $3$, $5$, $7$, $9$, $11$, $13$, $15$, $17$ sides, namely$$1, 35, 287, 1302, 4257, 11297, 25935, 53516, ...$$is given by the expression$$\frac{n^6+15n^5-95n^4+225n^3-266n^2+120n}{720}$$This seems to supply what OP requests: a fast way to calculate the number of triangles, not just for the regular pentagon but for any regular polygon with an odd number of sides.  For regular polygons with even $n>4$ sides, the expression is nearly accurate, but over-counts by a little due to one or more concurrencies of three or more diagonals. For example, it over-counts the regular hexagon, which has one 3-line concurrency, by $111-110=1$ triangle, and the octagon, which has eight 3-line concurrencies and one 4-line concurrency, by $644-626=18$ triangles.
[image: 3-line concurrencies]